# How add a a field obtained in a form to a table in access? How can I use VBA?

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I am working on an access database and have several fields on a table and the same fields plus another calculated field, resulting from a calculation of different field values, in a form. I want to be able to export this new field from the form into a field in the table. How can I do that? Do I really need to use Visual Basic access?

Comment: How about creating a query, do your calculation in the query and store it in a query field, and basing your form on the query? Normally you shouldn't store calculated values in a table.

Comment: Agree, saving calculated data is usually unnecessary and can be dangerous. Access tables now have a 'calculated' field type that allows simple calculations to take place in table; however, if there is any chance of ever migrating to another db platform, this field type will cause issues. And yes, saving calculated data requires code - macro or VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that in your form you have the calculated field obtained by a simple formula, you should create a new query, add the fields that you need from the tables and copy the formula for the calculated field from your form.

The query should be a 'create table query'

Executing the query you will have the calculated field into the new table.

If the form is more complex and you have VBA code to calculate fields, you should change the form to table view do a copy and paste to a new table with fields equals to the table view.

These workarounds are manual actions, if you need a real export functionality, I think that you need some VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for helping me. I changed the whole database and arranged the formulas into queries and worked for me.
Thanks from a real newbie